# Using Nexmo api to send sms through android app

Tags: java, android, sms, vonage

`do i need to add every number on Nexmo ,to which i need to send sms through nexmo,any help would be really great, am using volley library to do this

```
    params.put("api_key","********");
    params.put("api_secret","********");
    params.put("from", originator.getText().toString());
    params.put("to", destination.getText().toString());
    params.put("text", content.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Are you referring to the `from` parameter? Are you having any problems or errors to help us understand your question?

Comment: No the code is working fine,suppose i have to send sms to 10 users of my app , then, do i need to register all 10 numbers to nexmo account??? @PhillipShipley

Answer (score 0):

When you sign up for a Nexmo account it is initially in a restricted mode and can only send messages to your own phone number. After you top it off (add credit) the first time it will unlock the account so you can send to more numbers. If that doesn't work for some reason contact their support with your API Key and they can unlock it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add up to 10 whitelisted numbers during the trial phase.

This list can be found in your customer dashboard.

For more info - [Nexmo: How to Add Numbers to List of Permitted Destinations with Trial Account](https://help.nexmo.com/hc/en-us/articles/204014853-Nexmo-Trial-Period-How-to-Add-Numbers-to-List-of-Permitted-Destinations-)